# FFMPEG Lossless

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, lossless

How can I make a video still image + sound (audio file) lossless with ffmpeg? I want the still image video to sound just like the audio track/file if its possible, I dont want any transcoding. Also, I'd like to know if I can do it vp9 webm lossless if there is a way as well? I'm trying to make one single still image with sound (Music) video.

I've used

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -1 audio.mp3 -shortest -c:v libvpx-vp9 -lossless 1 output.webm` and it worked but not sure if its lossless

Comment: By 'lossless', do you mean you want the conversion/encoding process to be lossless, or you want the output file to be lossless? Because webm is a lossy format. Are you wanting a lossless audio or video or both? Also mp3 and jpg are also usually lossy. `ffprobe -i audio.mp3 ` will probably confirm this

Comment: i want everything lossless is that possible? sorry im new to this but what i want is the still image video output to sound just like like the audio file when you play it on file player, is that possible? and my other question is how i add one single still image and audio file from computer to make it a video?

Comment: The easiest way to achieve the desired output with *at least* the audio would be to copy to encoder settings, which would avoid a reencode. This is achieved with `-c copy` to copy the encoding for both video AND audio streams, `-c:v copy` would copy only the video encoding, resulting in a reencoding of the audio.  Finally, what will most likely work for you would be `-c:a copy` which avoids encoding audio.

The reason this might not work for video is that encoding can get kinda weird depending on the container whenever you loop imgs. If you want to avoid encoding completely i would use .mkv

Comment: can you please give me an example of .mkv parameter to avoid encoding completely? will this sound just like the audio file? i want the single still image loop video to sound like a normal mp3 or any other audio file? can you give me an example of any parameters or at least the .mkv one you mentioned please?

Comment: Yes, will go ahead and include it as an answer

Comment: can you please give me an example of .mkv parameter to avoid encoding completely? will this sound just like the audio file? i want the single still image loop video to sound like a normal mp3 or any other audio file? can you give me an example of any parameters or at least the .mkv one you mentioned please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.mkv is known for being extremely flexible when it comes to supporting encoders, though mileage varies when it comes to compatibility with video players (embedded, dedicated, or otherwise), so you might try mp4 first.

avoiding a re-encode on audio and video streams could look something like this:

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -shortest -c copy output.mkv`

Note that the filesize of this will likely be huge since you avoided reencoding the video stream at all, so the filesize of the video stream will probably be original image filesize * fps (if you didn't specify this, ffmpeg's default is 25 I think) * duration (in seconds), so this is not usually practical unless it is absolutely necessary
various optimizations are possible from this point, but that is outside of the question's scope.
this *should* work for .mp4 but shouldn't be considered as a catch-all

In the event that it doesn't work:
to go straight to mp4 (since the `-c copy` might present issues with the mp4 container; feel free to try though, if it works, then great), reencoding the video only:

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -shortest -c:a copy output.mp4`

Comment: one more question how do i add image and audio files from computer to ffmpeg please i dont know how to do it

Comment: I need to know a lot more information to be able to answer your question are you on a Linux system? Are you on a Windows system?

Comment: Sorry, Im on Windows 10 pro

Comment: In this example you would replace the ‘image.jpg’ and ‘audio.mp3’ with their respective filenames. Assuming the ffmpeg binary is on your PATH, then your shell would need to be in the same directory as your files, unless you use the full filepaths of the files

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: you said you successfully got `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -1 audio.mp3 -shortest -c:v libvpx-vp9 -lossless 1 output.webm` to work before, no? So you should know who to do this, right?

Comment: If ffmpeg is not on your path, then you can still use it from its current directory

Comment: sorry im confused. is there a video for this to explain? i know youre explaining but i would like visual to help me undertsand

Comment: I believe [this video](https://youtu.be/MPV7JXTWPWI) is a pretty good video if I recall correctly. It is for Windows 7 but should be almost exactly the same for Windows 10.

Comment: i figured it out. thank you so much. youve been very helpful and im very pleased

Comment: Then please mark the answer as the accepted answer. Glad I could help :-)